# trait Enumeratee is invariant in type From when using ADT

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

I am trying to compose an `Enumeratee.grouped` and an `Enumeratee.filter` to make a new enumeratee however I am running into a variance issue. The input and output types of my enumeratee are ADTs and I get the following error.

```
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee[OutputType,OutputType]
 required: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee[Product with Serializable with OutputType,OutputType]
Note: OutputType >: Product with Serializable with OutputType, but trait Enumeratee is invariant in type From.
You may wish to define From as -From instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

I have recreated my issue with a smaller example here (I understand this example could be rewritten as an `Enumeratee.collect` however, unless there is a way to combine a `Enumeratee.grouped` and `Enumeratee.filter` this will not help me.)

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed abstract class InputType
case class InputA(counter: Int) extends InputType
case object InputB extends InputType

sealed abstract class OutputType
case class OutputA(msg: String) extends OutputType
case object OutputB extends OutputType

val e: Enumeratee[InputType, OutputType] = Enumeratee.map[InputType] { 
  case InputA(counter) => OutputA(counter.toString)
  case InputB => OutputB
} compose Enumeratee.filter[OutputType] { 
  case OutputA("4") => false
  case _ => true
}
```

I can't redefine the `From` type on Enumeratee to be `-From` as the compiler error suggests because it is a play library. Is it a limitation of the library that you cannot use ADTs when composing enumeratees? Or is there a better approach for this use case (put a `ClassTag` somewhere, write this functionality another way, etc...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems ok. If you change `Enumeratee.map[InputType]` to `Enumeratee.map[InputType].apply[OutputType]` the inferencer gets the invariant type and it compiles just fine.

```
val e: Enumeratee[InputType, OutputType] = Enumeratee.map[InputType].apply[OutputType] { 
  case InputA(counter) => OutputA(counter.toString)
  case InputB => OutputB
}
```